# Am I able to set an observable to undefined or null?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable like this in my Angular class like so:

```
fullMember: Observable<Member | undefined>
```

and in the constructor:

```
this.fullMember = store.pipe(select(selectActiveMember))
```

and from this selection, I'm piping the information:

```
this.firstName = this.fullMember.pipe(filterUndefined(), map(m => m.firstName))
this.lastName = this.fullMember.pipe(filterUndefined(), map(m => m.lastName))
this.phoneNumber = this.fullMember.pipe(filterUndefined(), map(m => m.detail.homePhoneNumber))
```

Which all works, but then I want to make this Observable undefined to show the loading state for another `activeMember`

**What I've tried**

I've tried doing something like this in my `ngOnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

    this.fullMember.pipe().subscribe({
      next: () => undefined 
    })
}
```

But that got me nothing. I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible since googling didn't net me anything. Is it possible to make an observable undefined?

Comment: Looks like you are using ngrx. If that's true then you should dispatch the action to update the relevant state as `undefined`. That way your observable (selector) will emit value as `undefined`. You cannot set the observable value as undefined in subscribe.

Comment: All types can be undefined in JavaScript so Member | undefined is unnecessary as a Member can be set to undefined.

Comment: You can have a read of a library I created to make what you are trying to do easy. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: You're using `filterUndefined()` so it looks like you are purposely ignoring all `undefined` values. So why should it emit `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, it looks like you are using ngrx.

In this case, I suggest you to manage a dedicated field for the loading state. For example `loading`, with a dedicated selector.

It will improve readability and maintainability

When dispatching action `loadMember`, set inside the reducer the current loading state :

```
return {
   ...state,
   loading: true
}
```

Then, with action `loadMemberSuccess`:

```
return {
   ...state,
   activeMember: payload,
   loading: false
}
```

In your component ts:

```
loading$ = this.store.pipe(select(appSelectors.getLoading));
```

Then in template:

```
<my-loader *ngIf="loading$ | async">
</my-loader>
```